# Существительные или наречия?

Tags: морфология

Каков частеречный статус этих слов: [галстук] **бабочкой**, [губки] **бантиком**, [бровки] **домиком**, [читать] **вечерами** - существительные в творительном падеже или наречия?

---

В МАС не отмечено, что данные слова являются наречиями. У Ефремовой же сказано, что все слова (кроме "домиком") являются наречиями. Орфографический словарь классифицирует "вечерами" и "домиком" как наречие.

---

**Даю ответ на свой же вопрос, получив ответы от "Грамоты".**

---

В МАС зафиксированы не те слова, которые являются наиболее частотными по степени употребления носителями языка, а те, в которых переход из существительного в творительном падеже в наречие завершился окончательно (утратилась возможность задавать падежный вопрос), такими словами, например, можно считать ***"вечером", "зимой"*** и подобные им.

---

Позиции орфографического словаря РАН и "Русской грамматики 80" отличаются, поэтому решить вопрос о том, какая часть речи в приведенных примерах ([галстук] **бабочкой**, [губки] **бантиком**, [бровки] **домиком**, [читать] **вечерами**) можно по-разному: мнение **ОС** не является истиной в первой инстанции, по крайней мере в данном случае.

---

Разные исследователи решают этот вопрос по-разному, поэтому в различных словарях можно найти, к примеру, наречие **"вечерами"**, наречие **"домиком"** и т.п., однако это не значит, что данные слова нельзя считать существительными в **творительном падеже** (для них переход не завершен).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146451/discussion-on-question-by-ajgy---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

**Ответ изменен** (исправлен для соответствия с содержанием заданного вопроса, то есть дан без рассмотрения дополнительных тем)

**1. Об орфографическом словаре**

Всегда следует ориентироваться на орфографический словарь РАН. Например на сайте Грамота.ру:
Орфографический словарь: ***вечерами, нареч***.

"Научно-информационный орфографический академический ресурс «Академос» Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН содержит нормативное написание более чем 200 тыс. единиц русского языка. Электронный словарь постоянно пополняется…"
Подробнее  https://orfo.ruslang.ru/

**2. Читать вечером и вечерами**

В словаре РАН оба слова (***вечером, вечерами***) являются наречиями, а в МАС?

Информацию в вопросе следует уточнить (из какого издания взяты следующие сведения): «В МАС не отмечено, что данные (то есть указанные в вопросе) слова являются наречиями».

Слово «вечер» в словаре МАС есть, судя по следующей информации: [https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/вечером](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)

**ВЕ́ЧЕРОМ,** нареч. В вечернее время. Возвращаясь вечером с ярмарки, я останавливался на горе, у стены кремля, и смотрел, как за Волгой опускается солнце. М. Горький, В людях.Источник (печатная версия): Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.; Полиграфресурсы, 1999; (электронная версия): Фундаментальная электронная библиотека

Там же: [https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/вечером](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)

**ВЕЧЕРОМ**, нареч. В вечернее время. Поздно в. Источник: «Толковый словарь русского языка» под редакцией **Д. Н. Ушакова (1935-1940)**; (электронная версия): Фундаментальная электронная библиотека

Может быть, слово "вечером" числилось в наречиях **уже у Ушакова?** Другими словами, хронологию перехода в наречие **надо уточнять.**

**3. Общая информация о МАС и его изданиях**

Первое издание словаря вышло под редакцией А. П. Евгеньевой в Москве в 1957—1961 годах, второе издание, исправленное и дополненное, — в 1981—1984 годах[1]:97. При переиздании в словарь были введены...  Последующие издания «Словаря русского языка» были стереотипными.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Малый_академический_словарь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C)

Comment: Тогда почему не были зафиксированы другие слова из списка? Если брать во внимание эту логику, то слово в творительном падеже тогда вообще не может быть существительным, если при нем нет предлога или определения, к тому же в такой позиции оно даже не может являться обстоятельством. Слезы лились (чем, как) ручьем, Шел (чем, как) лесом.

Comment: Вы не поняли мою логику, а я не понимаю вашу. О парных вариантах я вспомнила по аналогии - там понятна необходимость различения. ДЛя наречия вечером существует парное существительное, хотя встречается оно редко. Тем не менее их тоже надо различать. А вот почему слово в Т.п. не может быть обстоятельством, я не понимаю. Падежные вопросы задают нам падеж, но при синтаксическом разборе правомерны только обстоятельственные вопросы (как и где).  С остальными словами надо разбираться по аналогии, да вы и не спрашивали об этом. А еще вы забыли поблагодарить меня за ответ и за внимание к вашему вопросу

Comment: Я редко вам отвечаю, а теперь постараюсь это делать еще реже. На этот вопрос дала ответ, чтобы прояснить дикуссию.

Comment: Не надо делать одолжений, вы написали бред, как и oleedd, а теперь пытаетесь съехать. Вы привели пример, где задать можно только один логичный вопрос к конкретному слову. Я же вам показываю: в той же самой позиции к словам подобного толка можно задать как минимум два вопроса - падежный для существительного, обстоятельственный для наречия.

Comment: Не буду делать одолжений, и риторику выбирайте! Что за жаргон? Из-за вас приходится удалять ответ. А я еще за ваш ответ проголосовала...

Comment: А что не так с риторикой? Назвать слова бредом и привести обоснования вполне манерная риторика. Ни один модератор не придерется.

Comment: (1) Ну, мне не очень нравится слово "бред", оно неуважительно по отношению к человеку. Особенно  при оценки ответа, данного на заданный вами же вопрос, не очень подходит. Ну, это  на нашем сайте вопросов и ответов. Это же не РАЗГОВОРНЫЙ чат, где многое допускается...   Вот я обычно пишу "спасибо за ваше мнение". если ответ меня не очень устраивает. Или вообще ничего не пишу. (2) А съехать – это разве не ЖАРГОН? Вроде бы в словаре не нормируется. Все-таки надо стараться поддерживать общий культурный уровень, не правда ли?

Comment: Кстати, oleedd высказал однажды интересное наблюдение: один наш участник называет бредом все, что он не понимает. Ну, это я просто к теме этого слова вспомнила его слова... А сама я оценочные мнения стараюсь по возможности не использовать (как бы не озвучивать, а думается ведь всякое). Вот вы, вероятно, хотели передать мне определенную информацию, а я ее как бы не слышу. Психологические приемы с обеих сторон :)  На форумах вообще много всякой психологии…

Comment: @Sharon Я пользуюсь этой версией: Словарь русского языка: В 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистических исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз., Полиграфресурсы, 1999. В ней нет слова "вечерами". Повторюсь, что мнение ученых ИРЯ РАН - это не Манна небесная. Надуются авторитетные лингвисты, которые не будут придерживаться такой позиции.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вероятно, "полный переход"  в наречия для "вечерами" зафиксирован только в последнее время,  в отличие от "вечером".  Я обычно ориентируюсь на РАН,  не задумываясь особенно  о других лингвистах — на этот источник сослаться можно. Но вообще вся эта кухня  (перехода слов в наречия) не очень понятна.

Answer (score 0):

Такие ситуации – это просто промежуточные вопросы строительства терминологии, то есть
когда есть характеристики подходящие под два термина, то люди просто договариваются, чем они будут считать это. Если есть разногласия в разных источниках, то просто считайте это для себя, чем хотите (из этих двух вариантов). Я так понимаю, что вам это нужно как учителю, а если есть разногласия, то это вряд ли будет в каких-то тестах или в чём-то подобном.

Я имею ввиду такие слова в целом, а не слова ‟вечерами” и ‟домиком”. Если про какие-то отдельные слова написано в авторитетном источнике, то здесь, конечно, нет разногласий.

Comment: А разногласий нет, в МАС просто нет их отдельно.

Comment: А я написал ‟если есть разногласия”. Если их нет – прекрасно!

Answer (score 0):

Большая тема, я бы тоже послушал ученых на этот счет. Могу накидать несколько соображений.

**Вечером**

```
Вечером, за которым должен был последовать расстрел, они спокойно почивали.
```

Здесь "вечером" распространяется предикативным оборотом. Такое распространение невозможно у наречий. Здесь это существительное.

```
    Поздно прошедшим вечером они спокойно спали. // Существительное, распространяется причастием
    Поздно прошедшим вчера они спокойно спали.   // Наречие не может распространяться причастием
    Вечер за вечером он сидел у окна. // Перед наречием не может стоять предлог
```

**[Галстук] шнурочком**

В [АГ-1980.](http://rusgram.narod.ru/1830-1861.html) пишут, что это существительное с падежным примыканием существительного-же:

> § 1838. Случаи примыкания творительного падежа следующие.
>
> 1. Примыкание тв. п. с субъектно-определительным значением к
>    существительным, соотносительным с глаголом: осмотр больных врачом,
>    объезд района инспектором, чтение романа автором, исполнение арии
>    Шаляпиным, открытие месторождения геологами. Значимая сторона связи
>    устанавливается на основе двояких смысловых соотношений: (инспектор
>    объезжает район) и (инспекторский объезд района), (автор читает роман)
>    и (авторское чтение романа) (второй член такого соотношения возможен
>    при наличии в языке соответствующего прилагательного).
> 2. Примыкание тв. п. к существительным конкретных значений, обычно
>    определяемых со стороны внешних признаков или свойств, качеств: платье
>    цветочками, сапоги раструбами, **галстук шнурочком**, город террасами;
>    привез ему записку карандашом из штаба (Булг.); Это был совершенно
>    ужасный этюд масляными красками (Симон.). Определение при этом часто
>    осуществляется через сравнение: усы кисточкой, колечком, щеточкой,
>    кепка блином, борода лопатой, сапоги бутылками, голова тыквой, каблуки
>    рюмочкой, лес стеной.

Comment: Спасибо за разумный ответ.